# How does this arithmetic expression works?

Tags: php, operators, arithmetic-expressions

```
$x = 5 /* + 15 */ + 7;
echo $x;
```

The output of this code is 12. 
Can anybody explain me how this works?

Comment: /* What do you think */

Comment: Oh comment... Didn't realise that... Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

The middle part is a comment, so everything between /* and  */ will be ignored. So 5+7=12 which is correct :)

Comment: Thanks didn't realise that